# Regarding file coulumn level validation

Tags: java, io

I am reading a text file abc .txt in as shown below

```
gfh  hgh  thf
---  ---  ---
fgh  sji irj    
rhf  dhh fhf
kji  idj ddt
```

and i am able to read it successfully (for all the coulums in the table I have developed a seprate pojo
along with getters and setters), the advantage is that I can get the value of complete row through  it getters .

Now in seprate class I have to made a method in which i have to sort of null check
that is no column value should be null and if any coulumn value is null then I should throw a new exeption

for example ..

```
gfh  hgh  thf
---  ---  ---
fgh  sji  irj   
rhf  dhh  fhf
kji  idj  ddt
fgq       fio
```

As shown below in the fourth row , second column the value is null and in that case I need to throw the new exception , please advise how to proceed for it

what I have tried is that..getting all the columns getter from s object

```
if (s.getgfh()!=null && s.gethgh()!=null  && s.thf() != null)
{// continue}
else
throw exception
```

Please advise for this